# Switching to systemd on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, systemd, init

I have linux mint 17.1 running on a laptop which takes forever to boot. To speed up the boot I want to switch to systemd. How can I switch to systemd?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about mint but on Debian:

> apt-get update
>
> apt-get install systemd

This will install the systemd packages but will not configure systemd as your init system.

Configuring for testing
To test systemd before switching to it by default, you can add the following boot parameter to the kernel:

> init=/bin/systemd

This can be done in the grub menu for a single boot - press "e" in the grub menu and add this to the kernel line. For example, depending on the options required for your particular system, it might look something like:

> linux   /vmlinuz-3.13-1-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/root-root
> init=/bin/systemd ro quiet

If PID 1 is systemd then your system is running with systemd.

Configuring as default
In order to use systemd you should also install systemd-sysv which provides the symlinks links for /sbin/init.

> apt-get install systemd-sysv

In order to boot your system with the newly installed systemd, simply reboot.

Source: https://wiki.debian.org/systemd

Comment: It says: Package systemd is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  systemd-services:i386 systemd-services

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install systemd-217 or newer  and repoint anything that doen't do it normally  to `/etc/lib/sysytemd/......`   but seeing as linux mint is ubuntu based it should change most with that install BUT moreover as mint is its own spin off a a 14.04 ubuntu codebase you are likely to have major pointing errors and selinux would be another likely issue.

Comment: The question is how to do that. And mint doesnt come with selinux.

Comment: systemd requires it tho